# Is it possible to build a generic enough queue that allows it to store any data type as an object?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Essentially, what i'm trying to implement is a generic `enqueue( Queue *queue, void *key )` function. I'd like this Queue to store any data Type. This is how I structured my queue:

```
typedef struct Node {
    void *key;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node *front;
    Node *back;
}Queue;

Queue* initializeQueue() {
    Queue *queue = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    queue->front = NULL;
    queue->back = NULL;
    return queue;
}

void enqueue( Queue *queue, void *key ) {
    Node *tempRef = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)); // Inserted Node will be in the back of Queue
    tempRef->key = key;
    tempRef->next = NULL;
    if ( queue->front == NULL && queue->back == NULL ){ // When the Queue is empty
        queue->front = tempRef;
        queue->back = tempRef;
    }
    else { // When the Queue is non-empty
        queue->back->next = tempRef; 
        queue->back = tempRef;
    }
}
```

But truth is, this implementation is wrong, since i'm keeping the parameter void pointer stored as an object and the address it points to is reliant on an outside data type( for example, like a char), which is not intended. For example, the following code would link the address &key to an object inside the queue:

```
char key = '-';
enqueue(queue, &key );
```

So ideally, i'd like to store objects that are not addresses inside my queue. However, how would one store an arbitrary data type as object inside the Node struct? Clearly, utilizing `void*` isn't a solution, as I've said above, so is it even possible to find a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use `enqueue(queue, "-")`? String literals decay to char pointers, and char pointers implicitly convert to void pointers. Or is there some other use case that doesn't cover?

Comment: @Useless yes, but that would only be a solution to `char`s being pushed to the queue. I'd like it to be polymorphic, basically.

Comment: @Cheatah So, there's no better way to do it other than defining and making the function call in two separate statements? Isn't this kind of behavior undesired?

Comment: Before answering this, there are some other questions to resolve: Does the queue store the pointer passed to it, or does it copy the object?  If the pointer, how will you make sure the referenced object lives long enough to still be usable later?  If the object, how does the queue know how many bytes to copy?  And in either case, when you get the entry back out of the queue, how will you know what type it is?

Comment: @Luiz: If you want real polymorphism or generic programming, you've picked the wrong language.

Comment: I have the feeling that this is a so-called "XY problem". You're asking how to implement a particular (and possibly very poor) approach to a problem instead of taking a step back and asking how to implement the underlying problem instead.

Comment: To answer just the very specific question that was asked, to avoid declaring a separate variable, you can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) of array type, e.g. `enqueue(queue, (int [1]){42});` will pass a pointer to a temporary `int` which is initialized by 42.  But this temporary will cease to exist at the end of the block, just like your local variable, so you'd either better have made a copy or else removed it from the queue by then, or you'll have a dangling pointer.

Comment: Compound literals are also a relatively obscure language feature, and this is an unusual way of using them, so people reading your code may find it hard to understand.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your replies, I'll study compound literals and come up with a solution myself. I have realized that my solution wouldn't work, since each object in my Queue is an address of a previously declared variable. Which means that enqueueing objects would either lead to their contents being changed or it would mean declaring several variables in my main(), which would make the queue redundant.

Comment: Another alternative way to use compound literals, maybe more readable, is `enqueue(queue, &(int){42})`.  I forgot that even compound literals of fundamental types are lvalues.  The lifetime issues are the same, though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It IS an XY problem, thank you so much for pointing that out. Thanks to you I've learned of this new communication and logical problem

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll be sure to check that out

Comment: In case it needs definition:  [classic X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: So, if it is an X-Y problem, edit your code to say what problem  you are _actually_ trying to solve.

Comment: @ryyker Okay. I'm rethinking my problem and my solution in order to at least clarify this discussion a little better

Comment: I've essentially completely changed my question. I sincerely hardly think it's possible, if even viable, since it's basically implementing Java all over again. I've done this mostly to bring a conclusion to this thread, I really didn't think that I would get to such a... hard problem, to say the least, and I apologize for not thinking this through. However, I did grow from this, and thank everyone that responded this thread very much.

Comment: OT: regarding: `Queue *queue = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`   This will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Always a good idea to inform the user when an error occurs

Comment: @user3629249 "in C, the returned type is void* which can be assigned to any pointer" --> is more like to any _object_ pointer.  A function pointer may be quite wider than a `void *`.  C lacks a truly universal pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to build a generic enough queue that allows it to store any data type as an object?

Yes.

Consider how `fwrite()` knows how to write the contents of any object:
by receiving the address of the object and it size.

`Node` needs to save the address of a copy of the object and its size.

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    // void *key;
    void *data;
    size_t size;
} Node;
```

`enqueue()` needs to expand ...

```
// void enqueue( Queue *queue, void *key )
void enqueue(Queue *queue, const void *data, size_t size)
// Address of the object --------------^^^^
// Size of the object ------------------------------^^^^
```

... and then allocate space for the copy and then copy it.

```
Node *tempRef = malloc(sizeof *tempRef);
tempRef->data = malloc(size);
if (tempRef->data == NULL) {
  free(tempRef);
  return true; // fail
}
memcpy(tempRef->data, data, size);
tempRef->size = size;
tempRef->next = NULL;
...
return false; // success
```

**If the object has pointers within it ...**

Only the pointers are copied, not the data they point to.

**Yet at this point the type is lost**

The *data* is stored, but the type is lost.

Upon de-queuing, all that is available is the address and size of the enqueued data, not its type.

The de-queuing can either assume the type - this is good enough if this code has a set of wrapper functions for the type ...

... or ....

also save the type (from a set of limited types) via some sort of enumeration.  Research `_Generic`.

---

Code simplifications / complexities occur if the type is the same throughout the queue or potentially different per node.

Good luck.